# Select matching element from jsonb in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the the table **orders** which contains a column called **stores** with a jsonb with many elements like

```
 id  status        stores
  1  in progress   [{"id": 1, "lat": 19.41, "lng": -99.18, "name": "Domino´s pizza condesa", "products": "3 tacos de cabeza"},
                    {"id": 2, "lat": 19.03, "lng": -99.9, "name": "Papa guapa roma", "products": "una papa"}]

  1  done          [{"id": 3, "lat": 19.44, "lng": -99.28, "name": "ABC", "products": "3 tacos de cabeza"},
                    {"id": 4, "lat": 19.23, "lng": -99.29, "name": "Papa guapa roma", "products": "una papa"}]
```

I want to query the table orders and select only the element from the json that matches `{"lat:19.41", "lng":-99.18}`

So I get something like

```
id  status        store_filtered
 1  in progress   [{"id": 1, "lat": 19.41, "lng": -99.18, "name": "Domino´s pizza condesa", "products": "3 tacos de cabeza"}]
```

I currently have

```
SELECT id, status, stores->0 AS stores_filtered FROM orders WHERE stores @> '[{"lat":19.41, "lng": -99.18}]'
```

But that 0 is what I need to make dynamic, to give me the element that matches not the first.

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming that you're using PostgreSQL 9.5 (or newer), you can use the [`jsonb_array_elements(json)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) (or `jsonb_array_elements(json)`) functions to "unnest" the array, and then choose.

For instance, you can try:

```
WITH orders(id, status, stores) AS
(
VALUES
    (1,  'in progress',
        '[{"id": 1, "lat": 19.41, "lng": -99.18, "name": "Domino´s pizza condesa", "products": "3 tacos de cabeza"},
         {"id": 2, "lat": 19.03, "lng": -99.9, "name": "Papa guapa roma", "products": "una papa"}]'::jsonb),

    (1,  'done', 
         '[{"id": 3, "lat": 19.44, "lng": -99.28, "name": "ABC", "products": "3 tacos de cabeza"},
           {"id": 4, "lat": 19.23, "lng": -99.29, "name": "Papa guapa roma", "products": "una papa"}]')
)
, expanded_stores AS
(
SELECT
    id, status, jsonb_array_elements(stores) AS single_store
FROM
    orders
)
SELECT
    id, status, single_store AS filtered_store
FROM
    expanded_stores
WHERE 
    single_store @> '{"lat":19.41, "lng": -99.18}'
```

Or, assuming that you already have declared your `orders` table, you could just use:

```
SELECT
    id, status, single_store AS filtered_store
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        id, status, jsonb_array_elements(stores) AS single_store
    FROM
        orders
    ) AS expanded_stores
WHERE 
    single_store @> '{"lat":19.41, "lng": -99.18}' ;
```

You can check version 9.5 at http://rextester.com/MQE36487.

---

NOTE: Although this does work, it looks a bit "unnatural" for a SQL database. It is normally easier to *normalize* the information, and reserve JSON just where a lot of schema flexibility is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

with r as (
select status, unnest(stores) as stores
from orders
)
select * from r where stores->lat='19.41' and stores->lng='-99.18'

Comment: with r as ( select status, unnest(stores) as stores from orders ) select * from r where stores->lat='19.41' and stores->lng='-99.18'

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification